# How do I extract correlations from correlation table and make a dataframe of pairs with the greatest correlations?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, lapply, correlation

I have a big correlation matrix with 68 varaibles. I want to extract varaible pairs, where the coef is greater than abs(0.40).

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c(0.5,4,5.4,-2,4), v2 = c(0, 45, -5.6, -0.5, 2), v3 = c(9, -9, 8.9, 12, 1), v4 = c(8, 9, 10, -1, 0.89), v5 = c(-1, 2, -0.36, -0.64, -4))
cor.mat <- round(cor(d), 2)
```

So, I know, how to extract coefs greater, than abs(0.40):

```
extr <- lapply(cor.mat, function(x){x[x>abs(0.40)]})
```

But what I need is a dataframe with 3 varaibles — Var1, Var2, Cor — which could display me something like that:

```
View(DF)

 Var1|Var2|Cor
 v1  | v4 |  0.58
 v4  | v5 |  0.58
 ................
And so on.
```

I do not understand, how to (1) extract varaibles' names, (2) form a dataframe with the following structure. I hope I explained properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row and column index where `cor.mat` value is greater than 0.4. We can use this index to subset rownames and column names respectively from `cor.mat` and create a new dataframe.

```
inds <- which(cor.mat > 0.4, arr.ind = TRUE)

data.frame(Var1 = rownames(cor.mat)[inds[, 1]], 
           Var2 = colnames(cor.mat)[inds[, 2]], 
            Cor = cor.mat[inds])

#   Var1 Var2  Cor
#1    v1   v1 1.00
#2    v4   v1 0.58
#3    v2   v2 1.00
#4    v5   v2 0.66
#5    v3   v3 1.00
#6    v1   v4 0.58
#7    v4   v4 1.00
#8    v5   v4 0.58
#9    v2   v5 0.66
#10   v4   v5 0.58
#11   v5   v5 1.00
```

Perhaps, using

```
inds <- which(cor.mat > 0.4 & cor.mat < 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

might be more helpful ?

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works on this sample code, but doesn't work on mine. The error is: `Error in inds[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: I am not exactly sure since it does not happen for the data you have shared. How different is your actual data than your real data? Do you have `NA` values in it? What is the output of `inds` in your case?

Comment: Yes, there are several `NA` in my data. The output of `inds` looks like that `row col
v1      3   2
v2      2   3
v3      6   5
v4      5   6
v5     8   7
v6     7   8
v7  13  12`

Comment: I fixed this problem, but another one has occured: `Error in cor.mat[inds] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: I think you have applied `which` on some other data and using it to subset some other data. Are you sure you are using the correct data?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in a compact way if we convert to `table`

```
subset(as.data.frame.table(cor.mat), Freq > 0.4)
#  Var1 Var2 Freq
#1    v1   v1 1.00
#4    v4   v1 0.58
#7    v2   v2 1.00
#10   v5   v2 0.66
#13   v3   v3 1.00
#16   v1   v4 0.58
#19   v4   v4 1.00
#20   v5   v4 0.58
#22   v2   v5 0.66
#24   v4   v5 0.58
#25   v5   v5 1.00
```